# Node.JS & Socket.io - Checking if the tab is selected

Tags: javascript, node.js

For my chat, I want to have notifications. These notifications will act like Gitter's notifications, where it changes the html title to show you have a message. I've googled how to accomplish this, but all answers only worked by checking when the tab is changed. For example,

```
socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
    // Append the message
    appendMessage(msg);

    // Check if the window is focused
    if (window.onfocus) {

        // If it is, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "ChatProject";

    }else{

        // If the user is on another tab, show there's a new message
        document.title = "[!] ChatProject";
    }
});
```

With the code above, it *always* shows the notification whether you're on the tab or not. How do I get it to show only when there's a new message?

Comment: Can you show the code that emits? Your current code looks correct

Comment: Hmm.. the code that emits works fine - `socket.emit('chat message', reply.val()); // Emit the message`

Comment: Interesting.. if you have the debugger open with a breakpoint in your `on` callback, then change tabs, does the title change right away, and your breakpoint does not get hit?

Comment: Actually I just realized that's the wrong code (I forgot to save the changes). With the code in the original post, it always shows the notification whether you're on the tab or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onfocus is an event. Not a state.

By adding a getter and setter to the events you can get the behavior described.

```
///////////////////////
//Setting OnFocusSate//
///////////////////////
var isFocused = true;


function onFocus(){
    isFocused = true;
};

function onBlur() {
    isFocused = false;
};

window.onfocus = onFocus;
window.onblur = onBlur;

///////////////////////
//Example Event Check//
///////////////////////

socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
    // Append the message
    appendMessage(msg);

    // Check if the window is focused
    if (isFocused) {

        // If it is, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "ChatProject";

    }else{

        // If the user is on another tab, show there's a new message
        document.title = "[!] ChatProject";
    }
});
```

Cryptic: This works, but when you click back on the tab, the notification doesn't go away. So, we'd have to change the if statement to this

```
       if (!isFocused) {    
        // If the user is on another tab, show there's a new message
        document.title = "[!] ChatProject";
        }
```

Then add this under it

```
window.onfocus = function() {
    document.title = "ChatProject";
}
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't test the edited code well enough. It's weird, the first time I send a message, it's fine. But when I send a second message (and so on), it shows I have a notification on the active tab. I made a .gif to so the changes http://i.imgur.com/U7sbnG6.gif